# symfony 2 sylius bundle lost (TranslationBundle )

Tags: php, symfony, bundle, sylius

I try to install `Sylius ResourceBundle` on my  project but when i run my symfony project, i get this error :

```
Class 'Sylius\Bundle\TranslationBundle\DependencyInjection\AbstractTranslationExtension' not found
```

I can't find `Sylius TranslationBundle` .

How can i fix it ?

Comment: I already have the same problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a [bug](https://github.com/Sylius/Sylius/issues/2447) in version 0.13. You probably want to use version 0.12 until the new one is more stable. Otherwise install the edge version (replace "~0.13.*" with "dev-master" in your `composer.json` file) and hope for the best.

Answer (score 2):

This is fixed in the 0.14@dev.